# Using the formal definition of a limit, show that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{6x^{2} + 3x}{2x^{2}+1} = 3$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Using the formal definition of a limit, show that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{6x^{2} + 3x}{2x^{2}+1} = 3$

I know that I'll have to find a suitable epsilon, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You might want to review our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). One piece of missing context that you should edit into your question is the formal definition of a limit. You mentioned epsilon, so it would be useful to your potential answerers to see what *you* think the formal definition is.

Comment: I think that I detect some confusion here. Traditionally the definition begins **For all $\epsilon>0$**, so that you don't get to choose the $\epsilon$, you  probably have to find some $M$ such that for all $x>M$ .....